# How do i link a submit button to my email address

Tags: html, forms, email, submit

How do I use the submit button to send the form, when filled, to my email address?

```
<header>MINIMALISTIC FORM</header>
<form id="form" class="topBefore">
<p>       <input id="name" type="text" placeholder="NAME"><br />
          <input id="email" type="text" placeholder="E-MAIL"><br />
          <textarea id="message" type="text" placeholder="MESSAGE"></textarea><br />
  <input id="submit" type="submit" value="GO!"></p>
</form>
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You need PHP to submit the form data and send it to a specified email.

Take a look at this HTML example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Simple Feedback Form</title>
</head>

<body>

<form action="send_simpleform.php" method="post">
<p>Your name<br />
<input name="sender_name" type="text" size="30" /></p>
<p>Email<br  />
<input name="sender_email" type="text" size="30" /></p>
<p>Message<br />
<textarea name="message" cols="30" rows="5"></textarea></p>
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Send This Form" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Now take a look at this basic PHP example:

```
<?
if (($_POST[sender_name] == "") || ($_POST[sender_email] == "") || ($_POST[message] == "") {
    header("Location: simple_form.php");
    exit;
}

$msg = "Email sent from wwwsite\n";
$msg .= "Sender's Name:\t $_POST[senders_name]\n";
$msg .= "Sender's E-mail:\t $_POST[senders_email]\n";
$msg .= "Sender's Message:\t $_POST[message]\n";
$to = "jack@xxxxxxx.com.au";
$subject = "Website feedback message";
$mailheaders = "From: My web site <www.testwebsite.com>\n";
$mailherders .= "Reply to: $_POST[sender_email]\n";
$mail($to, $subject, $msg, $mailheaders);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Simple Feedback Form Sent</title>
</head>

<body>

<h1>The following email has been sent</h1>

<p>Your Name:<br />
<? echo "$_POST[sender_name]"; ?>
<p>Your Email Adress:<br />
<? echo "$_POST[sender_email]"; ?>
<p>Message:<br />
<? echo "$_POST[message]"; ?>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Just found one here on SO to use as a quick example.

Keep in mind there are countless ways to do this, and no one is necessarily better than the other - it really just depends on the needs.

Source: [HTML and PHP simple contact form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642750/html-and-php-simple-contact-form)

Answer (score 0):

HTML does not have the ability to provide the server's capability of sending an email.
There are options available for your to send the mail, using an appliation server in the back end.

Currently what language/ application server are you using to listen to the request ? (Which server is sending this HTML page to be rendered on browser ?)