# HTML form to send email

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am not a developer but i am trying to build an RSVP site for my wedding. So i have a html form . i would like to be able to get an email each time someone filled the rsvp form. i know it can be done through php or js but do not know how to do it. here is my code below

```
<div id="rsvp" class="text-center" data-scroll-reveal>
            <div class="heading">
                <h2>RSVP</h2>
                <p><span></span><i class="fa fa-heart"></i><span></span></p>
            </div>
            <form role="form">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
                        <label for="input-name">Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input-name" placeholder="John Doe">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
                        <label for="input-email">Email</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="input-email" placeholder="name@domain.com">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
                        <label for="select-guests">Guests</label>
                        <select class="form-control" id="select-guests">
                            <option>1</option>
                            <option>2</option>
                            <option>3</option>
                            <option>4</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
                        <label for="select-attending">I am attending...</label>
                        <select class="form-control" id="select-attending">
                            <option>All Events</option>
                            <option>Ceremony</option>
                            <option>Reception</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg">I'm attending</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML and PHP simple contact form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642750/html-and-php-simple-contact-form)

Answer (score 0):

You can find an email sender php script, but you could also consider something like: http://www.123contactform.com/

Comment: Direct links are discouraging since it can leads to security issue and it is not reliable if the link is dead for someone who wants to reffer to this answer. Please consider adding your own example.

Comment: @Zeratops That's a contact form service. I can't give an example, it's exactly like adding a link to gmail.com Yes, gmail may be dead in the future...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<form role="form" action="MAILTO:someone@example.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">` instead of `<form role="form">` like [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_mail).

But that only opens the default mail program and inserts the form content. The users have to send it themselves.

If this is not what you want you have to use a server side script which creates the e-mail.

Answer (score 0):

You could use`MAILTO:` but it has a lot of disadvantages.
I prefer to use the PHP `mail` function if the server supports.
Instead of `<button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg">I'm attending</button>` use `<input type="submit" value="I'm attending" name="submit" class="btn btn-lg">`.

The following code works fine (I tested it several times).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div id="rsvp" class="text-center" data-scroll-reveal>
        <div class="heading">
            <h2>RSVP</h2>
            <p><span></span><i class="fa fa-heart"></i><span></span></p>
        </div>
        <form role="form" method="POST" action="">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
                    <label for="input-name">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="input-name" placeholder="John Doe" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
                    <label for="input-email">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="input-email" placeholder="name@domain.com" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
                    <label for="select-guests">Guests</label>
                    <select class="form-control" name="check" id="select-guests">
                        <option>1</option>
                        <option>2</option>
                        <option>3</option>
                        <option>4</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
                    <label for="select-attending">I am attending...</label>
                    <select class="form-control" name="check2" id="select-attending">
                        <option>All Events</option>
                        <option>Ceremony</option>
                        <option>Reception</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <input type="submit" value="I'm attending" name="submit" class="btn btn-lg">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $to= "user@example.com"; 
    $from = $_POST['email']; 
    $name = $_POST['name']; 
    $subject = "Invitation"; //Write whatever you want here
    $message = $name . " is with " . $_POST['check'] . " person(s) and attends " . $_POST['check2'];
    $headers = "From:" . $from;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
header('location: thank-you.html'); //redirects the user to another page that you made if the mail was send succesfully
} 
?>
```